# Collect every n lines from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, tail

I have a huge log file, which needs to be streamed over HTTP. For performance reason, I want to capture/collect every **n** lines and send it over. So, basically, what I want is n lines buffered output from a file. Is there a tail/head or any other Linux command to achieve this?

Comment: perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759562/extract-lines-between-two-line-numbers-in-shell  ?

Comment: `man split`, assuming you have sufficient space to store the same data volume twice. At least you could then send the parts at intervals. A script looping tail/head would not use extra space, but would need either to send all the data consecutively, or with a fixed sleep between sections, or to set up a series of jobs in `at`.

Comment: @amisax We can't mark questions here as dupes of questions on other sites.

Comment: I guess the network is the resource you want to preserve, logs can be highly compressed, `gzip`, [split,] transfer, [concatanate,] decompress.

Comment: @thanasisp it is not just about the network resource on the server that is spitting the logs but also about the resource on the other side of the http - the server that is actually processing these logs.

Comment: Then probably you would like to describe your situation in a more detailed way, to explain what you mean by "perfomance reason" (by editing the post, not in comments)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a combination of `awk` for the splitting and a separate `inotifywait` watching your "outgoing data" directory. E.g. create a directory called "outgoing" and whenever a new file appears, we'll send it out.

*Script 1*: Splitting via `awk` every 10th line and write to new file "bufferX" with increasing number X - adapt as required.

```
$cat split.awk

NR%10==1 {buffer="buffer"++i}

{
print > buffer
if (NR%%10==0) {system("mv "buffer" outgoing/")}
}
```

*Script 2*: watch the outgoing directory and send data whenever a new log batch appears. I just assumed you use `curl` for sending - adapt accordingly.

```
$cat watch_dir.sh

#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -m -o watch.logs -e moved_to --format '%w%f' outgoing/  |\
while read bufferfile
do
    curl -T ${bufferfile} http://taget.url && rm ${bufferfile}
done
```

Here `inotifywait` watches the directory "outgoing" for the `-e`vent of a file `moved_to` it, runs indefenitly with `-m`onitor mode, l`-o`gs to "watch.logs" and prints the detected file in the `--format` with path & file name. This last part we read for the `curl` command and delete the file after uploading.

Create the outgoing directory, then run:

```
bash watchdir.sh & <your_command_creating_output> | awk -f split.awk
```